# While loop not working accordingly

Tags: java, loops, arraylist, while-loop, switch-statement

The following code asks the user to input the description, price and quantity of item he consumed.

There is a while loop to ask if he wants to input more items! If he does, the program ask to insert another description, price and quantity of the other items, and so on.

If he doesn't want to input more items, the output is all the items he added to the array, and the total of the bill.

Problem is: the first time the while runs, it works, but on the second time if the user answer with "y", it returns an error, as if he jumped from the description right to the price of the second item. If the user type the description, then it gets an input mismatch exception.

Main Class:

```
package com.company;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    ArrayList<Gastos> billArr = new ArrayList<>();
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int qntItems = 0 , counter = 0;
    String ans;
    Gastos bill = new Gastos();

    while (qntItems == 0) {

        System.out.print("Want to input another item? Y/N: ");
        ans = input.nextLine();

        switch (ans){
            case "y":
                qntItems = 0;
                bill.setDescription();
                bill.setPrice();
                bill.setQuantity();
                bill.getTotal();
                billArr.add(bill);

                counter = counter + 1;
                break;

            case "n": qntItems = 1;
                    break;
            default: System.out.print("Invalid!");
                        System.out.println();
                        break;
        }
        input.close();

    }
    for (int i = 0; i < billArr.size();i++){
        System.out.print(bill.getDescription() + ", " + bill.getPrice() + ", " + bill.getQuantity() + ", " + "the total is: " + bill.getTotal());
    }

}
}
```

and the Gastos class:

```
package com.company;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Gastos {

private String description;
private double price, quantity, total;
private Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

public void setDescription(){
    System.out.print("Insert the item name: ");
    description = input.nextLine();
}

public void setPrice(){
    System.out.print("insert the item price: ");
    price = input.nextDouble();
}

public void setQuantity(){

    System.out.print("Insert the quantity: ");
    quantity = input.nextDouble();
}

public String getDescription(){
    return description;
}

public double getPrice() {
    return price;
}

public double getQuantity() {
    return quantity;
}

public double getTotal(){
    total = price * quantity;
    return total;
}

}
```

How can I handle this error?

Comment: Look at your 2nd loop closely. It should be: `System.out.print(billArr.get(i).getDescription().....` or simply put: `for(Gastos b : billArr){ System.out.print(b.getDescription()) }`

Comment: That last `for` loop can be `for (Gastos bill : billArr) {`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a bug in your 2nd loop.

It should be: 
`System.out.print(billArr.get(i).getDescription().....` 
or simply put:

```
for(Gastos b : billArr){ 
    System.out.print(b.getDescription()) 
}
```

Update 1: Another error is you close the `Scanner` at the end of the first loop. Move `input.close();` outside the loop or inside `case "n"`.

Update 2: You have another problem, you need to reinitialize `Gastos` every time you enter new details about it. So you need to do `Gastos bill = new Gastos();` right after `case "y":` and remove it from where you initialize it before the while loop. Your main should look like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    ArrayList<Gastos> billArr = new ArrayList<>();
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int qntItems = 0 , counter = 0;
    String ans;

    while (qntItems == 0) {

        System.out.print("Want to input another item? Y/N: ");
        ans = input.nextLine();

        switch (ans){
            case "y":
                Gastos bill = new Gastos();
                qntItems = 0;
                bill.setDescription();
                bill.setPrice();
                bill.setQuantity();
                bill.getTotal();
                billArr.add(bill);

                counter = counter + 1;
                break;

            case "n": qntItems = 1;
                input.close();
                break;
            default: System.out.print("Invalid!");
                System.out.println();
                break;
        }
    }
    for (Gastos bill : billArr){
        System.out.print(bill.getDescription() + ", " + bill.getPrice() + ", " + bill.getQuantity() + ", " + "the total is: " + bill.getTotal());
    }
}
```

I think you need to spend sometime debugging and understanding how java's objects work. These are basic errors which should be easily caught.

Comment: Actually the second loop works! What I meant is the second time the `while (qntItems == 0) {` runs, it gets an error.

Comment: on the console it appear the following `Want to input another item? Y/N: y
Insert the item name: insert the item price: ` as if the price overwrite the description. If I insert the description it gets an `java.util.InputMismatchException`

Comment: Thank you so much. I'm a beginner, and going to going to spend some time debugging.